# Video texture on a curve surface

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I want to implement a curve surface in WebGL, and map a video texture to the surface. Is it possible?

Something like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73906326/img.png

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can use video element as texture in webGl, so I'd say yes.

See http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/02/07/live-video-in-webgl/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

I would suggest modelling the surface in some modelling software and then exporting it to use it for webGL.

And process for linking video as texture can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Animating_textures_in_WebGL